# Digital signature (hash) of mp4 video

Tags: mp4

Is is possible to take a digital signature of an mp4 video? Is there a canonical way to do this, similar to how we use hashes to verify text file contents? thanks

EDIT: I want a way to digitally version videos uploaded to vimeo so that I can then refer to that specific video in documentation. I need it to be a "self-referencing" signature, not the vimeo url. Something in the meta data of the mp4? (this is for legal compliance reasons, so needs to be infallible rather than just saying "such-and-such url")

Comment: Please supply more details of what exactly you want to achieve and how (programming language/other information)

Comment: @Nissim - thanks, edit made to the original question...

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: @Nissim - either a command line utility or Java/Scala/Clojure

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't exist a canonical way to do this (to the best of my knowledge), but you have some options.

The first, is to assign an identifier to the material you are using (the standard for that is the [UMID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_Material_Identifier)) which is basically a 256-bit number, and is supported by most video editing software.

The other option that you can try is to simply do a hash of metadata reported by a utility (for example `ffprobe.exe`) which will give you a signature that's fast to calculate.

But, consider that fingerprinting video is not easy, as you can have the same **content** (video and audio) wrapped in a different **container** (i.e. mkv, mp4, avi, mxf). You can also have the same content encoded using a different **codec**. More so, you can have a file with the same container and codec but different stream's order.

Comment: On the other hand, why not use the perfectly legal URIs that vimeo is giving you? They are unique, and you want to use this to refer to them so...

Comment: many thanks for your answer. We can't use the vimeo URL's for legal reasons we don't own them so there is (technically) the possibility that they are not immutable. If we need to refer to the video in court we need to be 100% certain we are referring to the same video which was handed over.

Comment: To be 100% sure you'll need a cryptographic hash, which are sensible to bit variations so you have a conundrum. You can probably get a probabilistic algorithm that fingerprints video, but that won't be 100% sure. See if http://www.phash.org/ solves you problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about digital video fingerprinting? There is open source implementation pHash, unfortunately, last commit is from around 2013.